# Store test data from rails into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to store my test data in database automatically when i run my application.

The following is the data that i want to use:

```
INSERT INTO `crm_donation_email_types` (`id`, `emailtype`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'to', '2013-08-28 05:19:08', '2013-08-28 05:19:08'),
(2, 'cc', '2013-08-28 05:19:15', '2013-08-28 05:19:15'),
(3, 'bcc', '2013-08-28 05:19:26', '2013-08-28 05:19:26'),
(4, 'from', '2013-08-28 05:19:35', '2013-08-28 05:19:35');
```

I want to know where to add these lines?? I don't want to run either `rake db:migration/seed`
but i want when i start my application like start the server it should be included in the database. Any Idea???

Comment: in `config/initializers` folder create a file to populate the data

Comment: Can you tell me , the code i have to write in that file... as i am new and i haven't use to code in those files

Comment: yeah the files under `config/initializers` folder..... code are executed while your application is initialized or started

Comment: i have created a new file with name `test_data.rb` in config/initializer folder and paste the code as i show above. but having error i just want to know what is the exact code to place that lines in it!

Comment: in `test_data.rb` ou have to write `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO `crm_donation_email_types`..........")`

Comment: oooh sorry you have to connect first ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "myuser",
  :password => "mypass",
  :database => "somedatabase"
)  then execute that

Comment: can you write the exact code in answer??

Comment: see my post below........... there is code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't use [fixtures](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/TestFixtures/ClassMethods.html#method-i-fixtures) or [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)?

To use fixtures, you would place a `yaml` file in `spec/fixtures` or `test/fixtures` named `crm_donation_email_types.yml` and the contents would be

```
to:
  id: 1
  email_type: to
  updated_at: <%= DateTime.parse '2013-08-28 05:19:08' %>
  created_at: <%= DateTime.parse '2013-08-28 05:19:08' %>

cc:
  id: 2
  email_type: cc
  updated_at: <%= DateTime.parse '2013-08-28 05:19:15' %>
  created_at: <%= Datetime.parse '2013-08-28 05:19:15' %>

bcc:
  id: 3
  email_type: bcc
  updated_at: <%= DateTime.parse '2013-08-28 05:19:26'
  created_at: <%= DateTime.parse '2013-08-28 05:19:26'

from:
  id: 4
  email_type: from
  updated_at: <%= '2013-08-28 05:19:35' %>
  created_at: <%= '2013-08-28 05:19:35' %>
```

Rails will insert records according to this file when you run the unit test for this specific model. If you need these fixtures in other tests, then use the [`fixtures`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/TestFixtures/ClassMethods.html#method-i-fixtures) class method. Read [2.3 The Low-Down on Fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures) for all the details.

If you decide to go with factory_girl, read the [GETTING_STARTED](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) guide.

Answer (score 0):

1) create a file in `config/initializers/test_data.rb`

2) In that file

```
  conn = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( :adapter => "mysql", :host => "localhost", :username => "myuser", :password => "mypass", :database => "test_database" )

  conn.execute("INSERT INTO 'crm_donation_email_types' ('id', 'emailtype', 'created_at', 'updated_at') VALUES   (1, 'to', '2013-08-28 05:19:08', '2013-08-28 05:19:08'), (2, 'cc', '2013-08-28 05:19:15', '2013-08-28 05:19:15'), (3, 'bcc', '2013-08-28 05:19:26', '2013-08-28 05:19:26'), (4, 'from', '2013-08-28 05:19:35', '2013-08-28 05:19:35');")
```